# If $A \subset \mathbb{Z}$ and $\sup A$ exists, prove $\max A$ exists and $\max A = \sup A$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

If $A \subset  \mathbb{Z}$  and $\sup A$ exists, prove $\max A$ exists and $\max A = \sup A$.

I'm not quite sure how to prove that the maximum of the set $A$ exists. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a$ be the greatest integer less than $sup(A)$.  Then all elements of $A$ are less than or equal to $a$, since otherwise there is an element of $A$ greater than $sup(A)$.  But if $a$ is not in $A$, then all elements of $A$ are less than $a$, so, they are less then or equal to $a - 1$ ( being integers ), so $sup(A)$ is less than or equal to $a - 1$, and in particular less than $a$, which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

Remember the property of the supremum $s$ of the set $A$: for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $a\in A$ such that $s-a<\varepsilon$.

What if $\varepsilon=1/2$?

Answer (score 0):

$A$ has a maximum means $\exists m\in A \forall a\in A:a\le m$. Suppose $A$ does not have a maximum then $\forall m\in A\exists a\in A a>m$ (we negate the last proposition), that means that we can define $a_0\in A$ arbitrarily, $a_1\in A$ such that $a_1>a_0$, and so forth, getting an infinite sequence $a_0,a_1,...$ that is not bounded above, contradicting the fact that $A$ is bounded above. Thus $\max A$ exists.
Since $\max A$ exists we have $\max A=\sup A$

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: Surely you would not find a sequence in $A$ that is not bounded above, for then $\sup(A)$ wouldn't be an upper bound. The set $A$ would not even be bounded above, as your sequence $a_1,a_2,\ldots$ is contained in $A$, but not bounded above.

Comment: @Joffysloffy That's why I wrote "because otherwise".

Comment: That's still wrong. The supremum of $A$ exists, so the set is bounded above. Therefore, any sequence in $A$, *even if the maximum of $A$ does not exist*, is still bounded above by $\sup(A)$.

Comment: @Joffysloffy Ok i will write this more carefully, tell me if it's still wrong.

Comment: It is pretty much correct now. What you are not making rigorous though is the fact that a strictly increasing sequence in $\mathbb{Z}$ is unbounded. You should argue that since we work with integers, we have for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ that $a_n\geq a_0+n$ (use induction to show that). Now take $m:=\sup(A)-a_0+1$, then we see that $a_m\geq a_0+\sup(A)-a_0+1=\sup(A)+1$, so $a_m>\sup(A)$, but $a_m\in A$, which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Take an element $a$ of $A$, if $a=\max A$ then is done, but if not, then $B=\{x\in\Bbb{A};x\geq a\}$ is a discrete bounded set in $\Bbb{R}$, then it is finite, therefore it's just take the greatest element of $A$, let be $m\in A$ such element, the afirmation is that $m=\max A=\sup A$, if not, there exist a sequence of $A$ that converges for the $\sup A$, but is not possible because $A$ is finite!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Suppose a set $A$ has a maximum, call it $a \in A$ (note the fact that it's in $A$ is important), then we have
$$
\forall x \in A \; x \le a
$$
Now compare this to the definition $sup$ and look what's different. What can you deduce with $\epsilon = 1 / 2$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ be non empty and bounded from above. Then $s := \sup(A)$ exists and $a \le s\,\forall a \in A$ as well as $\forall \varepsilon \gt 0 \,\exists a \in A: s - \varepsilon \lt a$.

Choose $\varepsilon = 1$. Then by the above there exists $n \in A$ so that $s - 1 \lt n$ or equivalently $s \lt n + 1$. Then for all $m \in A$ it follows that $m \le s \lt n+1$. We claim that $m \le n$ for all $m \in A$ (we will prove this in a second). Because then $n = \max(A)$ from the definition of the maximum and $n = \sup(A)$ as well.

Assume $m \le n$ is **not** true, i.e. $n \lt m$ is true. But then $n \lt m \lt n+1$ for $n,m \in \mathbb{Z}$. This is a contradiction because $n,m \in \mathbb{Z}$. Therefore $m \le n$ is true.